# Python: Returning word count of each list item with at least two vowels

Tags: python, list, for-loop, count, character

I'm trying to first, count the lines in paragraph, which I've successfully done then count how many words is in each line that has more than 7 words:

```
lines = 0
wordCount=0
data = open("sentences.txt", 'r')

for lineOfText in data.readlines():
    lines += 1
    f1=lineOfText.split()
    wordCount=len(f1)
    if wordCount > 6:
      
      print(wordCount)
```

The output looks like:

```
13
15
17
14
14
12
13
16
11
14
16
12
15
14
```

Which is perfect, though now the hard part where I've been scratching my head for days now, reading and trying different things. I need to wittle done each line so it only counts the words with **AT LEAST 2 VOWELS**.

I've been playing with:

```
vowels = str.maketrans("aeiouAEIOU")
```

Though to no avail. Can anyone help me out here, point me in the right direction? Thanks community

Comment: How do you define a paragraph in the context of your data?

Answer (score 0):

```
count_words=0
for lineOfText in data.readlines():
    f1=lineOfText.split()
    for word in f1:
        if len([char for char in word if char in "aeiouAEIOU"])>=2:
            count_words+=1
```

Selects vowels from the word and gets the number of vowels

```
len([char for char in word if char in "aeiouAEIOU"])
```

Comment: unfortunately that now counts every word and gives me how many vowels are in each word and then totals them :(

0
0
2
5
9
15
etc

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this:

```
lines = 0
data = open("sentences.txt", 'r')

for lineOfText in data.readlines():
    lines += 1
    twoVowelWords = 0
    for word in lineOfText.split():
        if sum(letter in "aeiouAEIOU" for letter in word) >= 2:
            twoVowelWords += 1
    if twoVowelWords >= 6:
        print (twoVowelWords)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprension on you `f1` variable to filter the words that have two or more vowels.

```
def count_vowels(word):
    vowel_count = 0
    vowels = "aeiouAEIOU"
    for char in word:
        if char in vowels:
            vowel_count += 1
    return vowel_count

filtered_words = [word for word in fi if count_vowels(word)]
```

Then you just need to count filtered_words with `len(filtered_words)`

Also instead of counting the number of lines you could get it for the `len` of `data.readlines()`

Answer (score 0):

When used in an arithmetic context, the booleans True and False have the respective values 1 and 0

Therefore, a concise function for determining your vowel rule could be implemented as:

```
VOWELS = set('aeiouAEIOU')

def has_at_least_two_vowels(word: str) -> bool:
    return sum(c in VOWELS for c in word) > 1
```

...or for greater flexibility...

```
def has_at_least_N_vowels(word: str, n: int = 2) -> bool:
    return sum(c in VOWELS for c in word) >= n
```